# Passwordless Email Auth Firebase, Dynamic Links (FDL)

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm trying to setup password-less email authentication through firebase for my iOS app. I'm using the method send **signInLink** which require **actionCodeSettings** and in turn a url. I've discovered that this url has to be a dynamic link created on Firebase. I've gone to the firebase console  and white-listed a domain, but when I try to create the dynamic link on the console, I get **"An error occurred when creating new dynamic link"**.

I'm a little confused as to how I'm supposed to construct this dynamic link especially the deep link. I've been through Firebase's documentation, added a dummy App Store ID and App prefix (as I was told by Firebase support), but I can't seem to get a proper diagnosis behind this

If I try sending the sign-in email there is no issue, but when I click on the link I get a 400 error saying **"The requested URL was not found on this server"**.

Can anyone help me out with this?

```
actionCodeSettings.handleCodeInApp = true
    actionCodeSettings.url = URL(string: String(format: "my_dynamic_link", email.text!))
    actionCodeSettings.setIOSBundleID(Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!)
    actionCodeSettings.setAndroidPackageName("", installIfNotAvailable: false, minimumVersion: "12")

Auth.auth().sendSignInLink(toEmail: email.text!, actionCodeSettings: actionCodeSettings, completion: { error in
        if error != nil {
            print("Link Error: " + (error?.localizedDescription)!)
            let castedError = error as NSError?
            let FBError = AuthErrorCode(rawValue: (castedError?.code)!)
            switch FBError {
            case .invalidEmail?:
                print("invalid email")
            case .emailAlreadyInUse?:
                print("in use")
            default:
                print("Create User Error: \(error!)")
            }
        }
        else {
            print ("No Error")
        }
    })
```

Comment: So to clarify, in the Firebase Console, when you go to the Dynamic Links tab, do you see a link there, or does it say "get started"?

Comment: It shows me my whitelisted domain with an empty table that says "You have no dynamic links in this domain"

Comment: Ok so when you take the link and go to it in a browser like https://[your.link.here]/apple-app-site-association, are you able to see your app id in details? I apologize if I'm making you go through the steps you've already taken.

Comment: Going to the link in the browser produces a 400 error. My app id isn't present in the url once I've selected the link. I'm assuming this is because there is no actual dynamic link set up. I've whitelisted a domain, but am unsure why setting up the link always returns me an error. Does the domain require a specific kind of setup?

Comment: So you're saying that going to the link from the browser on your computer while adding exactly "/apple-app-site-association" to the end of the link produces a 400? Because I get a 400 if I don't include "/apple-app-site-association" to the path, but not if I include it. If you include it, you should get the App Site Association

Comment: Also, are you adding a dummy App ID Prefix? It has to be the actual App ID Prefix for your App that you get from the Apple Developer page.

Comment: Sorry, the app id prefix was not a dummy value. It was correct. However, adding "/apple-app-site-association" to the end of the file path doesn't remove the 400.

Comment: Alrighty, thanks for bearing with my questions. You mentioned you spoke to Firebase support. Can I get your case number? I want to open it back up because that sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: 8-5872000022868

Comment: Thanks! I just took a look and it looks like the support team member asked you for additional information: Firebase SDK version used,
Platform used and its version (iOS, Android),
Minimal repro (i.e. MCVE),
Steps to reproduce the issue,
Error logs or stack trace,
Expected and actual behavior,
Screenshots (if applicable),
Video reproducing the issue

Comment: If you can respond to the support team member showing the issue, especially with the link that shows the app site association data doesn't show, that would be useful. Right now I'd say the focus is resolving the Dynamic Links specific question before moving on to the passwordless email part because it seems the issue is with the link.

Answer (score 0):

You could try following the troubleshooting steps mentioned in the Firecasts video "Getting started with Firebase Dynamic Links on iOS - Pt.1 (Firecasts)" at 7:54 (https://youtu.be/KLBjAg6HvG0?t=474).

I was having the same issue and everything worked fine after:

1. deleting the app
2. restarting my phone
3. reinstalling the app

Currently the bug radar (http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=4999496467480576) is still open.